# Need to add some rows based on row & column references in Excel

Tags: vba

[image]

I have a table like above and I need to find Rows that contain the value D in Column 1 and find the corresponding values in Column Jul-15 and add them together.

However Column Jul-15 is not static, it will be passed by the user as a parameter, I have used Jul-15 as an example.

The Row value we are looking for as D is static.

The total sum should be returned to a cell in another worksheet.

All using VBA :) Is it possible ? I am unable to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMIF(A:A,"D",INDEX(A:Z,,MATCH("Jul-15",1:1,0)))`

Comment: When I use this statement I get an error stating expected list seperator or ). After this I tried giving all the references in double quotes and when I do this I get an error on the method function stating sub or function not defined.

Comment: This is a formula. Put it on the sheet.

Comment: Wow Thanks, its easier than VBA :) Appreciate the help!